# Restrict what someone types in a textbox

Tags: forms, excel, vba

Here's what I want to do and I have a problem.
I want to restrict what an user types in certain textboxes. I want to leave him type only numbers but after 3 numbers to add a ";". (eg. 007;123;003;005;).

The problem is that my textbox Controls are generated through a bunch of code. So I can't or I don't know how to set an action to these controls.

The code I'm using to generate the controls is:

```
Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add(
    "Forms.Label.1", "lreper" & l & pagina, True) 

With cControl 
    .Caption = "Reper" 
    .Width = 35 
    .Height = 9 
    .Top = 25 + k 
    .Left = 5 
End With
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about ... everything?

Comment: Yes. I have a form that has 3 textboxes. Someone has to enter some serial numbers of some products in those textboxes. The problem is that they sometime add text or use just 2 numbers instead of 3 for the serial number (eg. 03 instead of 003) and so on. So I want to restrict what they type in those textboxes... if they don't add 3 numbers a pop-up will appear to tell them how the correct SN looks like. Also I want after every 3 numbers to add a ";". That's it. Is this specific enough? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the key press event to restrict only numbers and the ";".  Along with check conditions.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

    Select Case KeyAscii
        '// Numbers 0-9
        Case 48 To 57
            If Len(TextBox1.Text) = 3 And Right(TextBox1.Text, 3) Like "###" Then
                KeyAscii = 0
                GoTo DisplayFormatError
            End If
        '//  Key ;
        Case 59
            If Len(TextBox1.Text) < 3 Or Not Right(TextBox1.Text, 3) Like "###" Then
                KeyAscii = 0
                GoTo DisplayFormatError
            End If
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
            GoTo DisplayFormatError
    End Select

    Exit Sub

DisplayFormatError:
    MsgBox "Please enter serial number in the format '000;000;000'", vbInformation, "Alert!"
End Sub
```

A better way would be to use a regular expression instead of the like method.

If you need help adding the events for your controls at runtime have a look at:

[Add controls and events to form at runtime](http://scriptorium.serve-it.nl/view.php?sid=13)

**EDIT (REQUEST BY TIAGO)**

Dynamic creation of Userform and Textbox with keypress event.  Uses modified example of above link.  Credit to original author.

Add reference - Under Available References, click "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility" and click OK.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MakeForm()
    Dim TempForm As Object ' VBComponent
    Dim FormName As String
    Dim NewTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim TextLocation As Integer
    Dim TextBoxName As String

    '** Additional variable
    Dim X As Integer

    'Locks Excel spreadsheet and speeds up form processing
    Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Create the UserForm
    Set TempForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)

    'Set Properties for TempForm
    With TempForm
        .Properties("Caption") = "Temporary Form"
        .Properties("Width") = 200
        .Properties("Height") = 100
    End With

    FormName = TempForm.Name

    TextBoxName = "MyTextBox"

    'Add a CommandButton
    Set NewTextBox = TempForm.Designer.Controls _
      .Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

    With NewTextBox
        .Name = TextBoxName
        .Left = 60
        .Top = 40
    End With

    'Add an event-hander sub for the CommandButton
    With TempForm.CodeModule

    '** Add/change next 5 lines
    'This code adds the commands/event handlers to the form
        X = .CountOfLines
        .InsertLines X + 1, "Private Sub " & TextBoxName & "_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)"
        .InsertLines X + 2, "KeyAscii = KeyPress(" & TextBoxName & ".Text, KeyAscii)"
        .InsertLines X + 3, "End Sub"
    End With

    'Show the form
    VBA.UserForms.Add(FormName).Show

    'Delete the form
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove VBComponent:=TempForm
End Sub

Public Function KeyPress(ByVal strText As String, ByVal KeyAscii As Integer) As Integer

    Select Case KeyAscii
        '// Numbers 0-9
        Case 48 To 57
            If Len(strText) = 3 And Right(strText, 3) Like "###" Then
                GoTo DisplayFormatError
            End If
        '//  Key ;
        Case 59
            If Len(strText) < 3 Or Not Right(strText, 3) Like "###" Then
                GoTo DisplayFormatError
            End If
        Case Else
            GoTo DisplayFormatError
    End Select

    KeyPress = KeyAscii

    Exit Function

DisplayFormatError:
    KeyPress = 0
    MsgBox "Please enter serial number in the format '000;000;000'", vbInformation, "Alert!"
End Function
```

**ANOTHER METHOD** (Using an event handler class)

Code in Userform:

```
Private colEventHandlers As Collection
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()   

    '// New collection of events
    Set colEventHandlers = New Collection

    '// Add dynamic textbox
    Set tbxNewTextbox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "MyNewTextbox", True)

    With tbxNewTextbox
        .Top = 25
        .Left = 5
    End With

    '//  Add the event handler
    Dim objEventHandler As TextboxEventHandler
    Set objEventHandler = New TextboxEventHandler

    Set objEventHandler.TextBox = tbxNewTextbox

    colEventHandlers.Add objEventHandler  


End Sub
```

And add a class module and rename it too "TextBoxEventHandler", then add the following code:

```
Private WithEvents tbxWithEvent As MSForms.TextBox
Public Property Set TextBox(ByVal oTextBox As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set tbxWithEvent = oTextBox
End Property

Private Sub tbxWithEvent_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub tbxWithEvent_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

    Select Case KeyAscii
        '// Numbers 0-9
        Case 48 To 57
            If Len(tbxWithEvent.Text) = 3 And Right(tbxWithEvent.Text, 3) Like "###" Then
                GoTo DisplayFormatError
            End If
        '//  Key ;
        Case 59
            If Len(tbxWithEvent.Text) < 3 Or Not Right(tbxWithEvent.Text, 3) Like "###" Then
                GoTo DisplayFormatError
            End If
        Case Else
            GoTo DisplayFormatError
    End Select

    Exit Sub

DisplayFormatError:
   KeyAscii = 0
    MsgBox "Please enter serial number in the format '000;000;000'", vbInformation, "Alert!"
End Sub
```

Comment: +1! The code that I told that wasn't working wasn't the dynamic forms, but the formatter in ###;###;###. I was able to add ####. Either way, thanks for the extensive explanation about dynamic controls!

Comment: Thanks, yes I understood you were talking about the formatter but it does works for me  - I cannot add 4 zeros.  Sorry I'm not sure why it is not working for you.  Anyway, hopefully this solves the OP's issue with dynamic controls.  Cheers.

Comment: Nice shot! Thanks for the explanation >> desserved at least a +1 btw

Answer (score 2):

Try Dataannotations / metadata

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141.aspx

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK and if i understood well, there is no way to handle this *before* user input.

Yet, you can use the `TextBox_Exit` event to format it afterwards. You can adapt [this sample of code](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Excel-1059/VBA-userforms.htm).

Comment: You understood well... I want to see what they type "live" ... if they type a letter a MsgBox will appear telling them how is the correct way to write in that textbox.

Comment: @Andrei Lion: Couldn't you use the TextBox_Change event to check for letters as the user types?  I understand you can't do the three-digit check this way, but this seems to solve half the problem.

Comment: @Excellll I can't use the TextBox_Change because the TextBoxes aren't added with drag and drop but with a small piece of code. Set cControl = form.Controls("io" & masina).Add("Forms.Label.1", "lreper" & l & pagina, True)
            With cControl
                .Caption = "Reper"
                .Width = 35
                .Height = 9
                .Top = 25 + k
                .Left = 5
            End With

Comment: @Andrei, add this info you commented above into your question. Your question is too vague to have more assistance from us than the assistance you already got.

Comment: BTW, the code above is adding a `Label` instead of a `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'd never use dynamic controls unless strictly required, I got puzzled by this question... so I'm thinking of it as a challenge. :-)

Googled around and most answers falls into the same solution, however most of them comes with a 'I couldn't make it work' comment as well, including this one here in SO [Assign on-click VBA function to a dynamically created button on Excel Userform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/566770/523742).

Here's the code I built... which obviously does not work, otherwise I'd say it *could be* a solution. The problem on it is that the keypress method it creates dynamically is not called when should be. To test it, just paste the code into a VBA form named 'myForm'.

I kept the TextBox1_KeyPress only for testing purposes, to prove the usability of the text field validator (I'm sorry @Readfidy, your code didn't work for me as expected. I was able to add more than 3 numbers in a row).

In case anyone else is interested in making this code works... I'd be happy to thank ;-)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim sTextBoxName As String
    Dim cControl As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim sMetaFunction As String
    Dim CodeModule

    sTextBoxName = "lreper"

    Set cControl = myForm.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", sTextBoxName, True)

    With cControl
        .Top = 25
        .Left = 5
    End With

    sMetaFunction = "Private Sub " & sTextBoxName & "_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)" & vbCrLf & _
        vbCrLf & _
        vbTab & "Set KeyAscii = EvaluateText(myForm.Controls(" & sTextBoxName & "), KeyAscii)" & vbCrLf & _
        vbCrLf & _
        "End Sub"

    Set CodeModule = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule
    CodeModule.InsertLines 60, sMetaFunction

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

    Set KeyAscii = EvaluateText(myForm.Controls("TextBox1"), KeyAscii)

End Sub

Private Function EvaluateText(ByRef oTextBox As MSForms.TextBox, ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger) As MSForms.ReturnInteger

    If ((Len(oTextBox.Text) + 1) / 4 = CInt((Len(oTextBox.Text) + 1) / 4)) Then

        If KeyAscii <> 59 Then KeyAscii = 0

    Else

        If KeyAscii < 48 Or KeyAscii > 57 Then KeyAscii = 0

    End If

    If KeyAscii = 0 Then

        MsgBox "Please enter serial number in the format '000;000;000'", vbInformation, "Alert!"

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I am not sure why you have had trouble with my code but I have tested it again on office 2010 and it works fine, an atempt at adding 4 zeros in a row results in the msgbox being displayed.  Please see the edit in my original post for an example on using dynamic controls.  Dynamic controls are certainly workable and I have used them many times in the past.  In some circumstances dynamic controls can be very useful, but I also try to avoid them.

Answer (score -1):

USE THIS CODE : NO CLASS NEEDED !

USERFORM CODE

```
Private Function QNumber(ByRef oTextBox As MSForms.TextBox, ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger) As MSForms.ReturnInteger
On Error Resume Next
Select Case KeyAscii
Case 45 '"-"
If InStr(1, oTextBox.Text, "-") > 0 Or oTextBox.SelStart > 0 Then
KeyAscii = 0
End If
Case 46 '"."
If InStr(1, oTextBox.Text, ".") > 0 Then
KeyAscii = 0
End If
Case 48 To 57 '0-9"
Case Else
KeyAscii = 0
End Select
End Function
```

TEXTBOX CODE

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
Set KeyAscii = QNumber(Me.Controls("TextBox1"), KeyAscii)
End Sub
```