# Disable/Enable button in Excel/VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying the following function in VBA/Excel:

```
Sub function_name()
  button.enabled=false
  Call Long_Function       ' duration: 10sec
  button.enabled=true
End Sub
```

For some reason, this button disabling does not work (it stays enabled in the excel work sheet)
I tried experimenting with DoEvents and delays, but no luck there.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following works for me (Excel 2010)

```
Dim b1 As Button

Set b1 = ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1")

b1.Font.ColorIndex = 15
b1.Enabled = False
Application.Cursor = xlWait
Call aLongAction
b1.Enabled = True
b1.Font.ColorIndex = 1
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
```

> Be aware that `.enabled = False` does not gray out a button.

The font color has to be set explicitely to get it grayed.

Comment: Good answer! The last sentence could be at the beginning of the post, I had to come twice because I didn't read all of it! Silly me :P

Comment: I think it's important to note that, in Excel 2010, setting `b1.Enabled = False` does not stop the actions associated with that button from occurring if it is clicked.

Comment: ... and **to deactivate the action (event), it must be unassigned** (Excel 2010) or one creates two buttons on the same spot switching their visibility as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/566965/1915920

Answer (score 3):

... I don't know if you're using an activex button or not, but when I insert an activex button into sheet1 in Excel called CommandButton1, the following code works fine:

```
Sub test()

   Sheets(1).CommandButton1.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: this works perfect, i think it has to do with 'screen refresh' or something while the 'long function' is running

Answer (score 2):

too good !!! it's working and resolved my one day old problem easily

```
Dim b1 As Button

Set b1 = ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1")


b1.Enabled = False
```

Answer (score 2):

Others are correct in saying that setting `button.enabled = false` doesn't prevent the button from triggering.  However, I found that setting `button.visible = false` does work.  The button disappears and can't be clicked until you set `visible` to `true` again.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me (Excel 2016) with a new ActiveX button, assign a control to you button and you're all set.

```
Sub deactivate_buttons()

     ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item("CommandButton1").ControlFormat.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

It changes the "Enabled" property in the ActiveX button Properties box to False and the button becomes inactive and greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using excel 2010 and below VBA code worked fine for a Form Button.
It removes the assigned macro from the button and assign in next command.

To disable:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button Name").OnAction = Empty
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button Name").DrawingObject.Font.ColorIndex = 16
```

To enable:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button Name").OnAction = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!Macro function Name with _Click"
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button Name").DrawingObject.Font.ColorIndex = 1
```

Pls note "ActiveWorkbook.Name" stays as it is. Do not insert workbook name instead of "Name".

Answer (score -1):

This is what iDevelop is trying to say [Enabled Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195862%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

So you have been infact using `enabled`, coz your initial post was `enable`..

You may try the following:

```
Sub disenable()
  sheets(1).button1.enabled=false
  DoEvents
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  For i = 1 To 10
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
  Next i

  sheets(1).button1.enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jonathan it seems like your waiting function doesn't seem to pull the desired `trigger` to change button properties. So please give this a try.

Comment: I found this too online, but this does not do the trick. I think this 'trigger' indeed is the problem. If I break after my function, the button does gets inactive.