# Stop user form from reopening

Tags: vba

I Created a user password form for a sheet but i don't want it to re-open if the user submits the correct information. i.e when you click on the sheet it opens, then if the password is correct it can close however if you try to click on the sheet it reopens again its kind of a loop.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As String
    a = "aaa"
    password = txtPassword.Text
    If password = a Then
        Unload Me
        ActiveWorkbook
    Else
        MsgBox "Password Incorrect. Please try again.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123017/disable-enable-button-in-excel-vba

Comment: @Raynoceros Please explain the relevance of the linked thread to this question.

Comment: You ought to have control over the `Protection` object. Therefore you can set the password. Therefore you can change the password when the workbook closes. The user won't know the second password and, therefore, can't re-open the file.

Comment: Incase there is a code i missedout

Comment: you didnt miss anything - no one posted code for you to copy paste... they just gave you instructions that you, as a developer, should be able to follow

Comment: I finally figured it out

Comment: "Global LoginFlag As Boolean" was the code missing  and a login flag i.e "LoginFlag = True"