# How to assign code for the command button created at runtime?

Tags: vba, excel, commandbutton

I am trying to create the code for the command button created at runtime. The command button created based on the dynamic input. I found the solution here

[Assign code to a button created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224511/assign-code-to-a-button-created-dynamically][1])

The problem is this code is used for one command button only, I have several command button created at runtime. This is my code.

```
For i = 1 To RevCounter

Set ctlTXT = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
ctlTXT.name = "Rev" & i
ctlTXT.Caption = Sheet4.Range("D" & i + 5).value
ctlTXT.Left = 18
ctlTXT.Height = 18: ctlTXT.Width = 72
ctlTXT.Top = 15 + ((i - 1) * 25)

Next
```

The question is, how to assign the code for command button created at runtime. For example if RevCount=5, there will be 5 command buttons created at runtime. I need to assign the code for each of the command buttons created.

Comment: not sure what is your question ? you want to know how to assign multiple `Sub` code to array of `CommandButton` ? where is the list of values you want ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I want to assign the code for each of the command button created at runtime. If the RevCounter=5, so 5 command buttons will be created and 5 codes is needed.

Comment: Have you tried [ctlTXT.OnAction = "nameOfMacroToRun"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2783413/1153513)?

Comment: @Ralph I tried already but im not sure whether the code doesn't work or I wrote the wrong code. Can you give me the example

Answer (score 0):

The process you want to use is to:

- add the button in a sheet
- add the related code using the `sub buttonname_click()` format

You have the first part, so we'll deal with the second here.  The code needs to be added to the relevant worksheet's code module; so this code would add code to the active sheet's code module, which is likely what you need.

```
Sub addcode()
    Dim subtext As String
    subtext = "Sub PrintStuff" & vbCrLf & "msgbox ""Hello World""" & vbCrLf & "End Sub"
    With Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveSheet.CodeName).CodeModule
        .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, subtext
    End With
End Sub
```

There's not really enough information in your question  to make this scaleable: what do you want the buttons to do?  Can you add the sub that you'd like to add?

Comment: The command button is in the user form, what I want to do is, when the user click on the created button, it will show another form with the correct information for the clicked button